# Touchscreen Issues

Tags: touchscreen

For Christmas I got a Lenovo i5 flex chromebook. For a while I was content with running basic Linux apps through the Debian virtual machine that comes with ChromeOS. However because I love to be able to tinker with stuff and hate the restrictions that ChromeOS forces on its users, I decided to wipe Chrome OS from my hard drive and install Ubuntu. (It was actually really easy despite chrome locking down its BIOS) Anyway once I finished with the install I noticed that my touch screen no longer worked. I had no issues under Chrome OS but under Ubuntu I could not figure out how to get it to work. Any Ideas? Thanks

Comment: what version of Ubuntu did you install? There was an issue with this touchscreen in older kernels, it should be fixed now (in theory)

Comment: Im running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS codename Jammy

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1469237/124466) tells you how to install Ubuntu with Depthboot, which has out of the box touch support.

Comment: By any chance did you install the MrChromeBox.Tech UEFI? How exactly did you wipe off Chrome OS?